# CSS Code: Background image not working

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have made a HTML website connected with a CSS.

```
body{
    background-image: url("imag.jpg");
}
```

When I run my code, why wouldn't the image show up? As my background image. I have tripled checked all the spelling and the file format of my image.

Does anyone know why the background image won't show up?

Comment: check image **relative** URI. Highly low possibility open image background show properties for browser.

Comment: check the error console, remember that path url is relative to your css file.

Comment: make sure it's in a style element (or linked stylesheet). Check your network logs to make sure there aren't any `404 imag.jpg not found` errors

Comment: Alright, so i checked my error console and it says that "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" however that image is present in my files.

Comment: It isn't present where the URL says to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your image is not on the CSS folder. If that line of code is in your style.css file, then its reading from that folder,
if the picture is in another folder then you go for example:

```
background-image: url("../img/imag.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

- Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the image in a directory **below**?
- Is the image in a directory **above**?

By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories. Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a look at my primitive example:
[image]

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward